# Python program won't append more than one value

Tags: python-3.x

Whenever I try to append(guesses) to the all_guesses variable it seemingly replaces the existing value from the previous loop. I want the program to record down all the player's number of guesses per game round but it only record the most recent value. I made sure the variable isn't in the while loop so that it doesn't overwrite it, so what's wrong? I'm really new to python programming so I can't seem to figure this out. Each time I run the loop the guessed and all_guesses values are reset to their original.

This is a snippet of my program:

```
def main():
    guesses = 0
    guessed = []
    all_guesses = []
    guess = input('\nPlease guess a letter: ').lower()
    letter = 'abcdefghi'
    answer = random.choice(letter)
    
    while len(guess) != 1 or guess not in letter:
        print("\nInvalid entry! One alphabet only.")
        guess = input('Please guess a letter: ')
        
    while len(guess) < 2 and guess in letter:
        if guess in guessed:
            guess = input("\nYou've already guessed that! Try again: ").lower()
            
        else: 
            if guess == answer:
                guesses = guesses + 1
                played = played + 1
                print("\nCongratulations, that is correct!")
                replay = input('Would you like to play again? Type y/n: ').lower()
                all_guesses.append(guesses)
```

Comment: I doubt this code would even work. What is `played` for example?

Comment: I didn't post the full code since it's too long. If you try to run the code I've provided, it will definitely not work. Played represents the rounds they've played but I didn't show that part of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer would be that `all_guesses` needs to be a *global* defined outside of `main` and the *replay* logic also needs to wrapped around `main`.

You seem to be missing logic, as you never modify `guessed` but expect to find things in there.  And there are dead ends and other missing parts to the code.  As best as I can guess, this is roughly what you're trying to do:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase as LETTERS

all_guesses = []

def main():
    guessed = []
    answer = choice(LETTERS)

    guess = input('\nPlease guess a letter: ').lower()

    while len(guess) != 1 or guess not in LETTERS:
        print("\nInvalid entry! One alphabet only.")
        guess = input('Please guess a letter: ').lower()

    while len(guess) == 1 and guess in LETTERS:
        if guess in guessed:
            guess = input("\nYou've already guessed that! Try again: ").lower()
            continue

        guessed.append(guess)

        if guess == answer:
            print("\nCongratulations, that is correct!")
            break

        guess = input("\nIt's not that letter. Try again: ").lower()

    all_guesses.append(len(guessed))

while True:
    main()

    replay = input('Would you like to play again? Type y/n: ').lower()

    if replay == 'n':
        break

print(all_guesses)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me the best you can, I'm aware of how my program is really bad and confusing. I'm basically self-learning and doing a bad job at it.